# How do I pull existing, hidden fields from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to avoid having hidden fields being overwritten when I post to the database. What code is needed in my Get/Post in order to pull existing fields and ensure they are maintained after the user clicks save?

I'm using sql/mvc 4/c#.

Comment: Without knowing the database, the website and the pretty well everything else we have no idea how to answer this question.  PLease add some specific as to what you are doing.  We are not psychic.

Comment: Good point. Apologies. New to all this.

Comment: post some view and controller code , and explain your question properly

Comment: Wish I could. Work stuff. Can't do that. I'll try to work this out.